# Who are all the kids in the final fight against Archdemon in the series?

Tags: daily-lives-of-high-school-boys

In the scene where Yanagin is remembering the final battle against Archdemon, there are a bunch of kids. The only two I can identify are of course, Yanagin (being the only girl there and charged with looking after Archdemon after the tied battle) and Yoshitake Tanaka, who was Rubber Shooter. I think Toshiyuki Karasawa was also there, but he may have gotten his scar from a previous run-in with Archdemon.

So I am wondering if all the kids that gathered, are characters that appear in the series.

Comment: Only 3 that i know of because the rest "died" so no need to remember them.